# Math.incrementExact(int a)

Tags: java, api

Why does not it throw and exception per API?:

> Returns the argument incremented by one, throwing an exception if the
>   result overflows an int.

```
System.out.println(Math.incrementExact(2_147_483_647 + 1));
```

returns -2147483647

Comment: Because you overflow in `2_147_483_647 + 1` which is evaluated before you call `Math.incrementExact` on the result

Comment: A method call cannot change how an expression whose result is passed to it is compiled.

Answer (score 9):

That's because your passing `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to the `Math.incrementExact` function.

Your expression `2_147_483_647 + 1` gets evaluated first, and since it overflows, the result is `-2147483648`. Then you pass that to `Math.incrementExact`, which results in `-2147483647`.

What you want to do is

```
System.out.println(Math.incrementExact(2_147_483_647));
```

This results in a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you *already* had one more than the max. `2_147_483_647 + 1` is evaluated first.

Try `System.out.println(Math.incrementExact(2_147_483_646 + 1));`